# Loop forth and back through image array _ SwiftUI

Tags: image, loops, timer, swiftui

I'm trying to make an animation from 5 pictures in my App. I want to click on a displayed Image and then start the animation that goes forth and back through array and ends/stops again on the first picture.

So far I've got this - I loop from 0 to 4 and then it just keep looping between 4 & 3.

Do you have any ideas how could I fix it?

Thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var activeImageIndex = 0
    @State private var startTimer = false

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.15, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    let myShots = ["MuscleUp1", "MuscleUp2", "MuscleUp3", "MuscleUp4", "MuscleUp5"]

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Image(self.myShots[self.activeImageIndex])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

                    .onReceive(self.timer) { time in
                        if self.startTimer {
                            if self.activeImageIndex != 4 {
                                self.activeImageIndex += 1
                            } else {
                                self.activeImageIndex -= 1
                            }
                        }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.startTimer.toggle()
                }
            }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the approach provided in [SwiftUI: Unable to animate images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60021075/12299030) will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! The solution from the link works perfect!

Comment: If referred answer helped it is a good SO citizen practice to vote it up, so it becomes more visible for other members. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem in the if statement used to increment `activeImageIndex`:

```
if self.activeImageIndex != 4 {
    self.activeImageIndex += 1
} else {
    self.activeImageIndex -= 1
}
```

When `activeImageIndex` starts and successfully goes to 4, it will then run like this:

`if self.activeImageIndex != 4` 4 == 4, therefore enters the `else` case `self.activeImageIndex -= 1`, `activeImageIndex` is now 3.

`if self.activeImageIndex != 4` 3 != 4, therefore enters the `if` case `self.activeImageIndex += 1`, `activeImageIndex` is now 4 again.

Then this repeats forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can add private var eg. `_up`

```
..
@State private var _up = true
......
```

and modify `.onReceive`

```
.onReceive(self.timer) { time in
    if self.startTimer {
        if self.activeImageIndex != 4 && self._up {
            self.activeImageIndex += 1
            
            if self.activeImageIndex == 4 {
                self._up = false
            }
            
        } else {
            self.activeImageIndex -= 1
            if self.activeImageIndex == 0 {
                self._up = true
            }
        }
    }
```